# D3.js array double quotes after .map

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have the following code:

```
d3.csv("static/data/river.csv", function(data) {
        var latlongs = data.map(function(d) { return [d.Lat,d.Lng]; })
        var lineArray1 = latlongs;
        console.log(lineArray1);
```

I get an output lineArray1 that looks like [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)....] and so on. But when I take a look at the actual Array(2)'s they look like:

```
["-35.48642101", "144.8891555"]  
["-35.48695061", "144.8893026"]  
["-35.48704283", "144.889315"]
```

Is there a way to get rid of the double quotes at the start? I tried lineArray1.map(Number) but this just generated an array of NaNs for some reason. The output I want is:

```
[-35.48642101, 144.8891555]  
[-35.48695061, 144.8893026]  
[-35.48704283, 144.889315]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `d.Lat` and `d.Lng` are strings, so if you want to convert them to numbers, call `Number` on them:

```
var latlongs = data.map(function(d) { return [Number(d.Lat), Number(d.Lng)]; });
```

Or, to not repeat `Number` twice, use `.map` again inside:

```
var latlongs = data.map(function(d) { return [d.Lat, d.Lng].map(Number); });
```

Or, in modern JS:

```
const latlongs = data.map(({ Lat, Lng }) => [Lat, Lng].map(Number));
```

Your `lineArray1.map(Number)` didn't work because `lineArray1` contains *arrays* (of numbers), and not numbers alone, and calling `Number` on an *array* doesn't work.